# FeedWordPress cron job code

Tags: cron, wordpress

FeedWordPress (RSS fetcher) plugin of WordPress is working well, but it doesn't have an option to update RSS every 5 minutes (default is 60 minutes) so the only way is clicking the UPDATE NOW button manually.

I am new and some guys told me to trigger it every 5 minutes using a `cron` job, so I tried that in cpanel

**First I tried this**

```
curl http://domain.com/?update_feedwordpress=true > dev/null
```

but was getting this error

```
/bin/sh: dev/null: No such file or directory
```

**Second I tried this**

```
wget http://domain.com/?update_feedwordpress=1
```

but now I'm getting this error

```
/bin/sh: /usr/bin/wget: Permission denied
```

(I used my `domain.com` in that place)

Any correct/exact working code?

Comment: correct path is /dev/null,  but for debug i recommend redirect output to some log

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
/usr/local/bin/curl --silent -L  "http://example.com/?update_feedwordpress=1" >/dev/null 2>&1
```

where you should replace `example.com` with your domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Null device is `/dev/null`

The /usr/bin/wget  does not seems to have permission to execute for the current user.

It may be easier to write a script (say mydebug.sh ) and run the script with cron

> id
> ls -l /usr/bin/wget
>
> curl ...

Then check for any obvious errors due to permissions.

Comment: Could you improve your question with information on  the user for the cron job, permissions on wget.